# Rails/ActiveRecord Domain Modeling - include a product's instructions as an attribute or their own model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say you're building a rails app using postgresql for your database. You have a Product model, and each product has some instructions that you could represent as an array of strings, either inside the Product model as an attribute, or in some form as its own model. Which of the below three options is "best"?

```
table "products"
  t.string  "title"
  t.text    "directions", array: true

#  or

table "products"
  t.string   "title"

table "directions"
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.text    "content", array: true

# or

table "products"
  t.string   "title"

table "directions"
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.integer "step"
  t.text    "content"
```

I've got this working fine using option number one but wonder if it could create headaches later down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's recommended to use option #3 on your example there. some reasons being

1) it's best to keep it simple when you are starting to write an app as your data model is constantly changing and you might need your `directions` table to be independently queryable and easily mutable.

2) easier for you to access associated model both ways `(@product.directions)` and `(@direction.product)`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that sounds reasonable. The only reason I tried to shoehorn directions into an attribute of Recipe is that will most likely not be used or accessed by any other model. But I don't know that for sure, and regardless option 3 does give the most flexibility.